# CSS filter blur defined edges not working properly in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, blur, css-filters

Microsoft Edge is giving me headaches...

I'm trying to use the CSS3 filter property to blur an image, but without ending up with blurred borders. The trick, which seems to work in all browsers except Microsoft Edge, is to nest the image in a container to which overflow:hidden is applied, and to scale the image to hide the blurred borders.

Here's my code:

```css
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.child {
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <img class="child" src="http://placekitten.com/100" />
</div>

<br>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#000;"></div>
</div>
```

This is what Chrome does, and it's exactly what I want:

[image]

However, this is what Edge does:

[image]

I just can't stop it from doing that. I've tried lots of things... applying negative margins to .child, applying translate3d to it, none of that seems to work.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: The only Edge I have here is on my phone, and the problem in the fiddle goes away when I pinch zoom. Even when I zoom in and then back out, the problem does not return.

Comment: It seems to me that Edge doesn't allow the blurred borders to be outside the parent container (and thus invisible) the way that other browsers do. For instance, if you apply a negative left margin to the child container, the left border is still there, even though it should be invisible.